# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject in android

Tags: java, android, mysql, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

Hi i have developed one android application.

The app purpose is retrieve data from mysql database and display in android device.

This is my android code:

```
public class RetailerActivity extends Activity {
 private final String NAMESPACE = "http://ws.testprops.com";
    private final String URL = "http://krish.jelastic.servint.net/Retrieve/services/Fetch?wsdl";
    private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://ws.testprops.com/customerData";
    private final String METHOD_NAME = "customerData";
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try {
        ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
        SoapPrimitive s = response;
        String str = s.toString();
        String resultArr[] = str.split("&");//Result string will split & store in an array

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);

        for(int i = 0; i<resultArr.length;i++){
        tv.append(resultArr[i]+"\n\n");
       }
        setContentView(tv);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

If i have to run the app means blank screen only displayed.it is taking too long time nearly 1 hour
also  am getting following error on my android console window:

```
  11-05 10:38:27.868: W/System.err(837): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject
  11-05 10:38:27.878: W/System.err(837):   at com.retailer.client.RetailerActivity.onCreate(RetailerActivity.java:29)
  11-05 10:38:27.878: W/System.err(837):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
  11-05 10:38:27.878: W/System.err(837):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
  11-05 10:38:27.878: W/System.err(837):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
  11-05 10:38:27.878: W/System.err(837):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
  11-05 10:38:27.878: W/System.err(837):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
  11-05 10:38:27.878: W/System.err(837):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 11-05 10:38:27.878: W/System.err(837):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 11-05 10:38:27.878: W/System.err(837):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
 11-05 10:38:27.878: W/System.err(837):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 11-05 10:38:27.878: W/System.err(837):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 11-05 10:38:27.878: W/System.err(837):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
 11-05 10:38:27.878: W/System.err(837):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
 11-05 10:38:27.888: W/System.err(837):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

please help me.how can i resolve this error.

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
```

to

```
SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
```

Comment: i have changed the above line and have to run the app means am getting this message on my emulator:anyType{}                                why this anyType{} message is displayed here.how can i resolve this error.please help me

Comment: anytype{} : means your not returning anything from webservice .

Comment: Hi this is my webservice code:http://pastie.org/5189059                  this is my wsdl link:http://krish.jelastic.servint.net/Retrieve/services/Fetch?wsdl   this is correct information only.then why am getting antType{} error.please give me solution for this

Comment: Hey check your webservice code .. i am not able to get any data from webservice ,change exception handling to  exc.printStackTrace(); to see if ur getting any issue . And your getting anytype as u have set custinfo as " "

Comment: i got the solution after i have to gave permission globally on my mysql database.first i have to set gave permission is static on my mysql database.thats why i have getting above error.